# Elementwise greater-than with three or more lists

Tags: python, numpy

Based on the following lists

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,3,4]
l3 = [3,4,2]
```

I want to do an elementwise greater than comparison such that the truth value in the resulting array is only true, iff the corresponding element in the 1st array is greater than the element in the 2nd array and the element in the 2nd array is greater than the element in the 3rd arry.

i.e.

```
print(elementwise_greather_than(l3,l2,l1))
[True,True,False]
print(elementwise_greather_than(l2,l1,l3))
[False,False,True]
print(elementwise_greather_than(l1,l3,l2))
[False,False,False]
...
```

numpy's `np.greater` only seems to work with two lists

```
import numpy as np
print(np.greater(l1,l3))
[False False  True]
```

but not with 3:

```
print(np.greater(l1,l3,l2))
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

So how can I do this comparison, assuming lists of equal lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming lists of equal length

```py
def elementwise_greather_than(a,b,c):
    return [x > y > z for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
numpy.logical_and(np.greater(l1,l2), np.greater(l2,l3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this works for n number of lists with equal length, where `n > 1`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,3,4]
l3 = [3,4,2]

def ewg(*args):
    "computes element wise greater than for more than one lists"
    result = [sorted(elems, reverse=True) == list(elems) for elems in zip(*args)]
    return result

ewg(l3,l2,l1)
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False]
```

```
>>> l4 = [10, 0, 10]
>>> ewg(l4, l3, l2, l1)
[True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a generalized version for any number of input arrays with `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

def elementwise_greater_than(*lsts):
    return ((-np.diff(np.vstack(lsts), axis=0)).min(axis=0)>0)
```

Outputs:

```py
print(elementwise_greater_than(l3,l2,l1))
#[True True False]
print(elementwise_greater_than(l2,l1,l3))
#[False False True]
print(elementwise_greater_than(l1,l3,l2))
#[False False False]
```